# Why does (XSLT-Function) generate-id() not work in SharePoint 2013 Content by Search WebPart?

Tags: 2013, xslt, content-search-web-part

Is there a reason that some XSL 1.0 functions do not work in SharePoint 2013 Content by Search Web Part? I recently came across the problem that a nested `<xsl:for-each>` does not work and neither does the function `generate-id()`.
Is there a reason for this, and does anyone know how to cope with this? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Could you include the relevant XSLT excerpt into your question?

Comment: Due to continuing problems with XSLT we choosed to develope our own Search Server Renderer to fullfill our reqirements.

Comment: Using HTML and JS Display Templates was no option for us for some resons including SEO